Linear regression model barely optimizes the intercept b
I've programmed a linear regression model from scratch. I use the "Sum of squared residuals" as the loss function for gradient descent. For testing I use linear data (y=x)
When running the algorithm, intercept b barely changes. Thus the slope m is not calculated correctly.
%matplotlib qt5 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=12345)

class LinearRegression():
    def __init__(self):
        self.X = None
        self.y = None
    
    def ssr(self, m, b):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(len(self.X)):
          sum += (self.y[i] - (m * self.X[i] + b) ) ** 2
        
        return sum

    def ssr_gradient(self, m, b):
        sum_m = 0
        sum_b = 0
        n = len(self.X)
        for i in range(n):
            error = self.y[i] - (m * self.X[i] + b)
            derivative_m = -(2/n) * self.X[i] * error  # Derivative w.r.t. m
            derivative_b = -(2/n) * error              # Derivative w.r.t. b
            sum_m += derivative_m
            sum_b += derivative_b

        return sum_m, sum_b
    
    def fit(self, X, y, m, b): # Gradient Descent
        self.X = X
        self.y = y

        M, B = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1), np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1))
        SSR = np.zeros_like(M)
        for i in range(M.shape[0]):
            for j in range(M.shape[1]):
                SSR[i, j] = self.ssr(M[i, j], B[i, j])


        fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
        gd_model = fig.add_subplot(121, projection="3d", computed_zorder=False)
        lin_reg_model = axes[1] 

        current_pos = (m, b, self.ssr(m, b))
        learning_rate = 0.001
        min_step_size = 0.001
        max_steps = 1000
        current_steps = 0

        while(current_steps < max_steps):
            M_derivative, B_derivative = self.ssr_gradient(current_pos[0], current_pos[1])
            M_step_size, B_step_size = M_derivative * learning_rate, B_derivative * learning_rate

            if abs(M_step_size) < min_step_size or abs(B_step_size) < min_step_size:
                break

            M_new, B_new = current_pos[0] - M_step_size, current_pos[1] - B_step_size
            
            current_pos = (M_new, B_new, self.ssr(M_new, B_new))

            print(f"Parameters: m: {current_pos[0]}; b: {current_pos[1]}; SSR: {current_pos[2]}")

            current_steps += 1
            
            x = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
            y = current_pos[0] * x + current_pos[1]
            lin_reg_model.scatter(X_train, y_train, label="Train", s=75, c="#1f77b4")
            lin_reg_model.plot(x, y)
            
            gd_model.plot_surface(M, B, SSR, cmap="viridis", zorder=0)
            gd_model.scatter(current_pos[0], current_pos[1], current_pos[2], c="red", zorder=1)
            gd_model.set_xlabel("Slope m")
            gd_model.set_ylabel("Intercept b")
            gd_model.set_zlabel("Sum of squared residuals")

            plt.tight_layout()
            plt.pause(0.001)
            
            gd_model.clear()
            lin_reg_model.clear()
        
        self.m = current_pos[0]
        self.b = current_pos[1]

    def predict(self, X_test):
        return self.m * X_test + self.b

lin_reg_model = LinearRegression()
lin_reg_model.fit(X_train, y_train, 1, 10)


This is the result for initial values m=1 and b=10:
Parameters: m: -0.45129949840919587; b: 9.50972664859535; SSR: 145.06534359577407

Obviously this isn't optimal because my data is linear. So the optimal parameters should be m=1 and b=0
But I cannot find the problem in my code. The algorithm prints different results based on the initial values, but it should print the same result over and over again as long as there is exactly one minimum of the SSR function.
I tried using different learning rates but the problem persists.

Why your derivative divide each term by n, when the loss function doesn't (unless I missed something)? If the thing you want to minimize is Σᵢ (yᵢ-mxᵢ-b)², then the derivative wrt m is Σᵢ -2xᵢ(yᵢ-mxᵢ-b), without any division by n. It is quite common to use rather (Σᵢ (yᵢ-mxᵢ-b)²)/n as loss function (which changes nothing, of course. Minimum is the same. The interest of doing so is to have some absolute meaning to loss function, independent from the size of the training dataset: the loss function is the average quadratic error, rather than the sum). And then, indeed, derivative for the

descent should be as yours. But here... you are just descending gradient n times more slowly than you should.

Which, with that toy example, is probably not enough to explain your problem (since n is small. 7 or 8, I guess.

Also, it is quite surprising to stop when either of the parameter don't move a lot. Why stop if gradient happens to be parallel to one of the axis? There is no reason for that. You probably meant to say and here. Stop as long as none of the parameter evolve sufficiently.

Basics of neural networks is to plot loss vs iterations/epochs, where you will see if the loss is decreasing or not, instead of just trying to interpret what happens from the weight changes. Also other people have told you that you might be training for too little iterations.
